# Datepicker bootstrap dateTimePicker parameters not taken into account

Tags: parameters, datepicker, bootstrap-4

I have a form for registration, asking for birth date, so I used Bootstrap's DatePicker to fill this role. My issue is that I gave parameters to the .datetimepicker() function and yet it's like some aren't there.

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label class="col-md-2 control-lable" for="dateNaissance">Date
                            de naissance</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input id='birthDatePicker' type='text' class="form-control"
                                    ng-model="patientController.patient.dateNaissance"
                                    placeholder="Date de naissance" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(function() {
                                $('#birthDatePicker').datetimepicker({
                                    format : "dd/mm/yyyy",
                                    maxViewMode : 3,
                                    language : "fr",
                                    autoclose : true
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

As you can see above I asked for the datePicker to be in FR, with only a date to choose and then autoclose. Yet, when I choose my date, firstly it isn't in FR and secondly it asks me to choose a time after the date.
I've been searching again and again but I didn't see anyone doing it differently, this is how everyone do it and it works for them.

[image]

I've checked many time if I didn't forget a css or js but no, everything's in order. So I'm really confused as to why this does not work as I expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

To support FR locale, you have to import the locale file (see https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/i18n.html):

```
<script src="bootstrap-datepicker.XX.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Changing the start date can be done by setting `startDate` option property (see https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate):

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    startDate: '-3d'
});
```